# cannot install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0rc0

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0rc0 not work

python version Python 3.7.0

I get the following error when trying to install tensorflow-gpu in version 2.3.0rc0:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0rc0
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: There is no `2.3.0rc0` listed on PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/#history

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this question is about installation with `conda`, not `pip`

Answer (score 3):

`rc0` refers to a pre-release version. Since tensorflow 2.3.0 has been officially released in [July 2020](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.3.0) there is, for obvious reasons, no pre-release candidate available anymore. You are probably following some old tutorial or similar.
Try simply dropping the `rc0`

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0
```